# Systematically disabling language extensions on projects automatically in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Apparently it's good for a person who is currently using VisualStudio to learn should disable Language Extensions for each project. Is there a way for each project to automatically disable Language Extensions? I'd find it tedious to constantly have to set up each project's settings when I just want to use the project to learn how to code in C++.

Answer (score 0):

> Systematically disabling language extensions on projects automatically in VisualStudio

I am afraid there is no such option on Visual Studio instead of project to disable language extensions. But we could use a workaround to resolve this issue:

The workaround:

Create a `Directory.Build.targets` file and set it in the solution folder with following content:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <DisableLanguageExtensions>true</DisableLanguageExtensions>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

This setting will work for all projects in your solution.

Check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017) for some details.